# Changing the color for custom progress Bar in Android at Runtime

Tags: android, android-widget

I have made a custom progress bar and set its color in a drawable file:

> ```
>   <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
>   <clip>
>        <shape>
>        <corners android:radius="30dip" />
>        <gradient
>             android:startColor="#CCFF33"
>             android:centerColor="#33CC33"
>             android:endColor="#009933"
>              />
>        </shape>
>    </clip>
> ```

After searching a while online, I found a way to create a `progressBar` with a `textView` on top, so that text indicates the percentage of progress in the progress bar.

Once I click on a button, the progress starts. I have set the color as green. After the progress reaches 100%, I want it to start again, only this time its color should be red.

I tried to do that using `setProgressDrawable`, But the progress bar dissapears once I click the button. Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Hi panaastha, i am also looking this runtime color changing for Custom Progress wheel. if you get answer post your answers here.. its usefull for all..

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck at the same problem, and I found the solution [here](http://miroprocessordev.blogspot.jp/2012/09/android-how-to-change-progress-bar.html)

In short, the trick is using Drawable's getBounds/setBounds

```
Rect bounds = mProgressBar.getProgressDrawable().getBounds(); // get current bounds before change drawable
mProgressBar.setProgressDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.use_different_drawable_here));
mProgressBar.getProgressDrawable().setBounds(bounds); // set bounds back
mProgressBar.setProgress(50); // you need to set progress again, because after changing drawable, progress is reset to 0 (I think so)
```